# In Ubuntu generated PDF graphs change colours when used

Tags: python, pdf, colors

I generate many graphs using either Spyder or terminal (I)Python (Python 3.7) in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, and I have noticed that if I load such a PDF graph in open office or online on overleaf the colours change. Blue becomes purples and green become neon green. No matter what I try, I cannot fix this. Remarkably, this problem does not occur with PDFs generated in Windows.

The images look fine in both Adobe reader and Document viewer (soft dark blue and soft green instead of the colours you see here), but the graphs look terrible once used in Open Office or upload anywhere online. It makes no difference if I generate the images in either Spyder or in the terminal with ipython or python.

Please find an example overleaf project with graphs here: https://www.overleaf.com/3185682316znynyqsfwmzk

Can anybody help me out?
Thank you!

ps. When trying a screen shot of a faulty image and a good one, they both go through the filter and the faulty one looks even more purple now:
[image]